# Trying to copy a certain range from several worksheets and paste into one worksheet as transposed, with each column in one line

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to copy the same range from all worksheets, and paste transposed into one worksheet.
I want to get one line for each column in the destination worksheet.
What I have tried so far looks like this:

```
Sub contracts()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim DestSh As Worksheet
Dim DestShLastRow As Long
Dim i As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set DestSh = wb.Sheets("Total table")
    DestShLastRow = DestSh.Cells(DestSh.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    i = 1
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name = "Total table" Then Exit Sub
        sh.Range("h3:h14").Copy
        DestSh.Range ("a" & i)
        .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .PasteSpecial Transpose = True
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End With
    i = i + 1
    Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
End Sub
```

When I run this code, I get an

> 1004-error, saying that "PasteSpecial method of Range class failed.

Anyone who has any advice on how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think you forgot the `With` in the code snippet (probably just a typo here).

Comment: That's right, just a typo.

Comment: I would replace `If sh.Name = "Total table" Then Exit Sub` with `If sh.Name = "Total table" Then Exit For`... If the sheet in discussion is not the last one, the code stops when it is reached.

Comment: I would also remove the line `.PasteSpecial Transpose = True` and move `Transpose` above, resulting: `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose = True`. Of course, after adding `With` in front of `DestSh.Range ("a" & i)`...

Comment: You can also avoid using the Clipboard bay using an array: `Dim arr As Variant` at the declarations area, then `arr = sh.Range("h3:h14").Value` followed by `.Resize(ubound(arr,2), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)` in the `With ... End With` area.

Comment: Like this:
`For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name = "Total table" Then Exit Sub
        arr = sh.Range("h3:h14").Value
        With DestSh.Resize(UBound(arr, 2), 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
        End With
    i = i + 1`
Unfortunately, it still does not work.

Comment: I told you to replace `Exit Sub` with `Exit For`... Otherwise, if that specific sheet is not the last, the code will exit/Stop. Is your "Total table" sheet the last? And, if you use `With ... End With`, you must use it inside the of this area...

Comment: Not a problem as the sheet will always be the last sheet. But tried to change to `End For`, and still get an error message on the .Resize argument. "Compile error: Method or data member not found".

Comment: `Exit For`...  What error do you receive?

Comment: Compile error: Method or data member not found

Comment: I do not have space here... I will post an answer for this part. Did it. Does it now return any error?

Comment: Could you test the code, please? It shouldn't return any error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code, in the iteration part, in this way:

```
Dim arr As Variant
For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If sh.Name = "Total table" Then Exit For
    arr = sh.Range("h3:h14").Value
    DestSh.Range("a" & i).Resize(, UBound(arr, 1)).Value = _
                             WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arr)
    i = i + 1
 Next
```